# How to use boost::hana::unpack with the constructor, instead of function?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, metaprogramming, boost-hana

Given this sample code, how to use `pars` to call a constructor to create a `Foo2D` object?

```
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/unpack.hpp>

class Foo2D {
public:
    Foo2D(int x, int y):m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

int main() {
    auto pars = boost::hana::make_tuple(10, 20);
    Foo2D foo1(10, 20); //my intention
    Foo2D foo2 = boost::hana::unpack(pars, Foo2D); //fails
}
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using lambda for this?

Comment: Use lambda? `boost::hana::unpack(pars, [](auto&&... args) {return Foo2D(args...);})`.

Comment: @Jarod42, r3mus Yes, of course... Apparently, I am still new to the c++ metaprogramming. Thank you for such a quick reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors are not function or functor. You might use lambda or regular functions:

```
boost::hana::unpack(pars,
                    [](auto&&... args) {
                        return Foo2D(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>
constexpr auto ctor = [](auto&&...args)
  noexcept(noexcept(T{ decltype(args)(args)... }))
  -> decltype( T{ decltype(args)(args)... } )
  {
    return T{ decltype(args)(args)... };
  };
```

Now:

```
Foo2D foo2 = boost::hana::unpack(pars, ctor<Foo2D>);
```

should work.

Or:

```
// Object that represents constructing an object of type T:
template<class T>
struct ctor_t {
  template<class...Args>
  constexpr auto operator()(Args&&...args) const
  // propogate noexcept:
  noexcept(noexcept(T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }))
  // SFINAE friendly:
  -> decltype( T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } )
  {
    // notice this expression is repeated twice above:
    return T{ std::forward<Args>(args)... };
  }
  template<class A0, class...Args>
  constexpr auto operator()(std::initializer_list<A0> il, Args&&...args) const
  noexcept(noexcept( T{ il, std::forward<Args>(args)... } ))
  -> decltype(T{ il, std::forward<Args>(args)... })
  {
    return T{ il, std::forward<Args>(args)... };
  }
  constexpr ctor_t() {} // some compilers require this

  template<class...Args>
  constexpr (*operator T() const)(Args...) const {
    return +[](Args...args)->T {
      return ctor_t<T>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
  explicit operator bool() const = delete;
};
template<class T>
constexpr ctor_t<T> ctor{};
```

if you are afraid of the lambda version.  This version also supports a leading initializer list and implicit cast-to-factory-function-pointer for a fixed signature.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e35ebd4050299b40).  Test code:

```
// construct an int 7:
auto x = ctor<int>( 7 );
std::cout << x << "\n";

// get a pointer to a constructor function
// that constructs an int from a short:
int(* pf)(short) = ctor<int>;
// run it:
std::cout << pf(0) << "\n";
```

Comment: And create 2 variants, one with `()` and one with `{}` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 In an industrial strength one, I'd also use a class instead of a lambda, and have `operator()(initializer_list<T>, Ts&&...)` as well as `Ts&&...` for more perfect perfect forwarding.

Comment: The way it is used is cool, but the definition of the `ctor` will definitely be not understandable for the average (any?) C++ programmer in my organization. I wish this class was part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski Well, if it makes you feel better, I added a more verbose version with a few more capabilities.  You can now take a function pointer returning `T` that takes arbitrary arguments and do `T(*pfunc)(some_args) = ctor<T>;`.  ;)

Comment: As I said - your API is wonderful. Simple and elegant. Even more so now :-). But I am hesitant in introducing so complex C++ code that defines `ctor` in our project when all of us are rather data scientists, not dedicated C++ programmers, and would require many hours of dedicated work to actually follow and understand this code. If it was in the standard library, we could simply treat it as a black box, and never bother to understand.